# IllegalArgumentException: "Object" is not a known Entity type

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

So, i'm doing a project in JAVA EE, with JPA (Glassfish Server 4.1.2).
But got this error when I'm doing persist with my Facade :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: be.isl.prj.story.entity.Universe@3b28b3d6 is not a known Entity type.
```

And here my files :

Controller (IndexBean) :

```
package be.usl.prj.story.controller;

import be.isl.prj.story.dao.UniverseFacade;
import be.isl.prj.story.entity.Universe;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

/**
 * IndexController
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class IndexBean implements Serializable{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String test;

    @Inject
    private UniverseFacade universeFacade;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){

    }

    public IndexBean() {
    }

    public void doTest(){
        Universe universe = new Universe("YEAH", "REallyNew gen");
        /*
        // this works :
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StoryGeneratorPU");
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.persist(universe);
        */
        this.universeFacade.create(universe);
        //System.out.println(this.universeFacade.find(139).getName());
    }
}
```

AbstractFacade :

```
package be.isl.prj.story.dao;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="StoryGeneratorPU")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StoryGeneratorPU");
        this.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void create(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        T object = entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
        return object;
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        List list = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        return list;
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        List list = q.getResultList();
        return list;
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
        int count = ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        return count;
    }
}
```

UniverseFacade :

```
package be.isl.prj.story.dao;

import be.isl.prj.story.entity.Universe;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Stateless
public class UniverseFacade extends AbstractFacade<Universe>{
    public UniverseFacade() {
        super(Universe.class);
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        return this.entityManager;
    }
}
```

Universe Entity :

```
package be.isl.prj.story.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "universe")
public class Universe implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="universe_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="universe_id_seq", sequenceName="universe_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @Column( name = "id_universe" )
    private int idUniverse;
    @Column( name = "name" )
    protected String name;
    @Column( name = "content" )
    protected String content;

    // ALTER SEQUENCE universe_id_universe_seq RENAME TO universe_id_seq;

    public Universe() {

    }

    public Universe(int idUniverse, String name, String content) {
        this.setIdUniverse(idUniverse);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setContent(content);
    }

    public Universe(String name, String content) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setContent(content);
    }

    public int getIdUniverse() {
        return idUniverse;
    }

    public void setIdUniverse(int idUniverse) {
        this.idUniverse = idUniverse;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }  

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    } 
}
```

Persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="StoryGeneratorPU" transaction-type="JTA">
      <class>be.isl.prj.story.entity.Universe</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally the Stack trace :

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy391.create(Unknown Source)
    at be.isl.prj.story.dao.__EJB31_Generated__UniverseFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:434)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at be.isl.prj.story.dao.UniverseFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.create(Unknown Source)
    at be.usl.prj.story.controller.IndexBean.doTest(IndexBean.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: be.isl.prj.story.entity.Universe@3b28b3d6 is not a known Entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at be.isl.prj.story.dao.AbstractFacade.create(AbstractFacade.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor545.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 60 more
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Could it be some kind of classloader problem? You could try debugging `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.getDescriptor(Class)` method. There are few mentions of bugs in this code e.g. [Bug#3947714](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.4.2/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/sessions/AbstractSession.java#2208).

Comment: You are using a JTA in your persistence.xml. After EntityManager injection, you don't have to reinstantiate again by calling the EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Yeah that was that, thank you !